# I have a marble vanity that needs to be trimmed off

Tags: marble

We need to replace the toilet but the small counter top is in the way. Is there an easier way to cut this piece off without removing the mirror and entire sink top?[image]

Comment: That doesn't look much like [marble](https://www.google.com/search?q=marble+countertops&rlz=1C1MSIM_enUS575US575&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikx-CHsO7UAhUTxCYKHey2CpIQsAQIigI&biw=1920&bih=1110) to me.

Comment: That answer didn't help me any,

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. The answers are down below in the 'Answers' section.

Answer (score 6):

That toilet should be able to be removed without disturbing the shelf return on the vanity top. Generally speaking the toilet only needs to lift about two inches to clear the hold down bolts. There is more than enough space below the shelf for that......and just in case it was not you can remove the tank cover to gain an additional 1.5 inches or so.

Comment: If your issue is that your replacement toilet is too tall... get a different toilet. Your goal of cutting back the top is (a) hard/time-consuming to do well and (b) causes problems supporting the mirror.

Comment: Yeah. And cutting it off will look really bad too. That return on the vanity top is a nice handy feature that does not make sense to just hack off.

Comment: We are wanting a taller toilet (17"). The one in there is unusually short. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Do you know if they make a higher toilet with a low tank? We are senior citizens and I don't like falling onto the stool lol

Comment: @Mkent - Size of available toilets is something you will have to research. I have no idea of the total height dimension under the vanity top return in your instance. I can say that I have lived in two houses that had vanity top returns just like that and both had the more conventional tank type toilets as opposed to the "low boy" type that you have now. Note that toilets that have the more conventional type of seat base and separate tank do not have to be installed all as one assembly. The tank can be slid into position after the base unit is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely polyester Fiberglas with a lot of limestone filler.  It will cut fairly easily like hard wood ( and dusty). The cut face will be dull , the surfaces have a layer of gel-coat ( polyester) to give gloss. You can polish it some with sand paper.Sorry , I did not read the question carefully; the other answer is good.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I appreciate your help and kindness, I'm researching now to find something that will work